# Reducing variance of Monte Carlo estimates via a known relationship

Tags: variance, optimization, covariance, expected-value, computational-statistics

Here's a simplification of the actual problem, but I believe it captures the essence of it.

Say we are interested in estimating the expectation of a stochastic time series. We can simulate the time series, so we can come up with the estimate, $\bar{x}(t)$, by just averaging many time series. $x$ could be a vector. We also estimate the covariance matrix, $\Sigma(t)$, in the usual way.

Say I have some equation that relates the two estimated quantities.
$$f(\Sigma(t)) = g(\mathbb{E}x(t))$$

$f$ and $g$ are known and are at least continuous. The goal is to reduce the variance of the estimates. Can I somehow "correct" the estimates, $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{\Sigma}$? It seems like nonlinear least squares might help, but I'd rather not cook up my own method if there's already theory out there.

Are there are already methods and theory out there for this sort of problem?

Thanks.

Edit: Changed the equation such that $g$ is a function of the expectation of $x$.

Comment: variance reduction methods (eg control variates) typically require a relationship with the underlying random variable not its expectation. could you give the exact problem you are trying to solve (namely the constraint equation).. are f & g invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a simple example like the Poisson $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ distribution, the mean is $\lambda$ and the variance is... $\lambda$ as well! Hence you can estimate $\lambda$ as
$$\eqalign{
\hat{\lambda}_{1n}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
\hat{\lambda}_{2n}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2\\
}$$
When comparing both estimators, $\hat{\lambda}_{2n}$ is more variable as predicted by theory:
[image: convergence of $\hat{\lambda}_{1n}$ [brown] and $\hat{\lambda}_{2n}$ [blue] to $\lambda$]

However, using the relation $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\text{var}(X)$$ (or $f=g=\text{id}$ in your notations) cannot produce a better estimator since  $\hat{\lambda}_{1n}$ is the best unbiased estimator ([Rao-Blackwell-Lehmann-Scheffé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem)).

Comment: It seems that the theorem precludes the possibility of finding a better estimator just from a relationship between the moments. Is that the right interpretation?

Comment: Based on a Poisson sample, you cannot find a better estimator than $\bar x_n$, hence the connection between mean and variance does not help.